# Can NCR forgive me for nuking the Long 15?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So, at the end of the Lonesome Road add-on I chose to bomb both Legion and NCR, which of course maximizes my infamy with both factions. I'm on my umpteenth play-through and I'd like to repair my reputation with the NCR, even if I need to use console-command cheats.

After some tweakage, my Pip-Boy now tells me I'm "liked" by the NCR, and I've removed the ["Don't Tread on the Bear!" quest](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Don't_Tread_on_the_Bear!) (which completed saying I'm a "terrorist")... but still official NCR reps attack me on sight.

Did I miss something?

Comment: It seems like the most plausible way to do this, which might be closed to you, is to complete Lonesome Road *before* the quest "Render unto Caesar" which resets your reputation with both the NCR and the Legion.

Comment: Actually, the rep reset triggers are different for both the NCR and the Legion, render unto caesar resets legion reputation (or, removes the negative reputation, infame iirc). NCR rep is reset when you get the offer to meet the ambasaddor. After coming out of the lucky 38 for the first time.

Comment: @Ids Yeah, it's the same basic moment though. Forgive my shorthand.

Comment: Is reloading the game prior to the launch and setting NCR reputation as Idolized an option?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz no problem. It can be annoying, just wanted to be clear.

Comment: @Wilerson Nope, fallout NV tracks two reputation statistics, fame and infame.

Comment: @Wilerson actually it is. You will have max fame and infamy, putting you at neutral standing with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like LessPop_MoreFizz mentioned, the only way to normally prevent the infame hits is to do the add-on before starting the [Things that go Boom](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Things_That_Go_Boom) and [Render unto Caesar](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Render_Unto_Caesar) quests. The only way to prevent the [infame reset triggers](http://www.falloutwiki.com/The_Apocalypse#Notes) is thus to not enter the lucky 38 or the tops casino before finishing the add-on.

To reset the infamy of the factions use the following [console commands](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Fallout:_New_Vegas_console_commands):

For the NCR use:

```
setreputation 1 000f43de 0
```

For the Legion use:

```
setreputation 1 000f43dd 0
```

This keeps your normal fame, it just makes them forget all the bad stuff you did.

I think that simply removing the [don't tread on the bear](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Don%27t_Tread_on_the_Bear) quest is not enough. When this quest is failed certain NCR NPC's dissappear from the game. I think you need to reset the quest status back to phase one, and enable the NPC's again.

Try this to reset the quest:

```
setstage 00167f0e 1
```

And use these commands to enable the two NPC's (replace refID with 00116840 (Crocker), and 001206fe (Moore):

```
prid refID
disable
enable
kill 
resurrect
moveto player
```

(For the best effect stand at the position the NPC would normally appear).

Not 100% sure this is all you need to do, the don't tread on the bear quest might set some more variables that you need to reset yourself, look at the [quest console commands](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Gamebryo_console_commands#Quests) and try a few of those.

Comment: @ewall Did it work?

Comment: Sadly... it didn't work :( But the idea about resurrecting the key NPCs was a good one. I had infamy like -50 and fame at plus 50, and the Pip-Boy showed me as "Liked"--but I was still attacked by a lot of NCR. Oh well... played on. It was kind of fun doing the Yes Men ending when I had to kill all my NCR "friends" as well as the Legion "foes".

Answer (score 0):

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_reputations  If you scroll down this page a bit, you'll see a helpful reputation table.  It says that reputation isn't on a sliding scale (unless you do the NCR/Legion quests that set infamy to 0).  You can't become Vilified (100 infamy), then get 200 Fame and be idolized.  You keep all infamy and fame you get during the game, so, if you get 100 fame, and 100 infamy, you basically be even (neutral) rep-wise.

So, in your case, I would suggest becoming idolized with both the NCR and Legion before you nuke them.  That way, according to this table, even if you take the max infamy hit (100), you're rep will go from "Idolized" to "Wild Child" with both factions, and Wild Child is Nuetral, not hostile.  In addition, if you haven't done the NCR/Legion quest to reset your infamy, you can become idolized with that faction again.  As far as being branded a terrorist, and having NCR hit squads coming after you, I don't know if it affects that or not.  Hope this helped.

I don't have confirmation on this, but I'm at a point in the game where I'm idolized with both factions, haven't used console hacks (you dirty cheater), am doing Lonesome Road now, and plan to nuke them both.  I can give you confirmation once I've done it myself.